# What does the Star0 instruction do in V8?

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8, bytecode

I was analyzing JavaScript bytecode generated with

```bash
node --print-bytecode <file>
```

And I came across this instruction

```
0xb899c88b0bc @    4 : c4                Star0
```

So, I was wondering what is the purpose of `Star0`. I tried searching for some documentation, but I didn't find anything relevant.
I already have experience with assembly languages and Python bytecode, so don't worry about using technical jargon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means store accumulator to register r0. Originally it was star r0. Here's the doc with the change: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1g_NExMT78II_KnIYNa9MvyPYIj23qAiFUEsyemY5KRk